# UI thread freezes during textbox invoking

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker, freeze

Why UI freezes during textbox invoking from separated thread

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(DoStuff);
        t1.Start();
    }

    void DoStuff()
    {
        using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            string page_src = wc.DownloadString("http://bing.com");
            textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { textBox1.Text = page_src; }); // freezes while textbox text is changing
        }
    }
```

Meanwhile backgroundworker works perfectly - UI doesn't freeze

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw1.DoWork += (a, b) => { DoStuff(); };
        bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void DoStuff()
    {
        using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            string res = wc.DownloadString("http://bing.com");
            textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { textBox1.Text = res; }); // works great
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you do `t1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)` before starting it?

Comment: Still same. Btw UI freezes just for few hundred milliseconds

Comment: You actually do not need a synchronous Invoke, for UI you're free to call BeginInvoke only. Moreover try to set a smaller text. Maybe it's just little bit big for a standard TextBox

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I just decreased text length to 10k symbols and UI doesn't freeze. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not because of invoke. Your UI queue is full, and it may be because:

1. You are calling `DoStuff()` frequently
2. You are doing other heavy jobs on UI

**Update:**

According to deleted comment putting 50K of text in text-box was the source of problem. Consider using a smart text box which loads data on demand. There should be one ready out there.